# Meaning of "polynomially larger"

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics, computational-complexity

For example

Is $n$ polynomially larger than $\frac{n}{\log n}$? Than $n \log n$?

Is $n^2$ polynomially larger than $\frac{n}{\log n}$? Than $n \log n$?

I am trying to understand the difference because apparently the first line isn't, but the second is (Master Theorem).

Comment: Possibly relevant. [Link 1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158754/what-does-it-mean-when-we-say-that-some-function-is-polynomially-bigger-smaller). [Link 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109742/master-theorem-how-is-n-log-n-polynomially-larger-than-n-log-4-3). [Link 3.](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/DiscreteMath/IV.6.pdf).

Comment: It says it doesn't apply to $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \log^2 n.$ and yet the answer does appear to be $\Theta(n \log^3 n)$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Polynomially larger" means that the ratio of the functions falls between two polynomials, asymptotically. Specifically, $f(n)$ is polynomially greater than $g(n)$ if and only if there exist generalized polynomials (fractional exponents are allowed) $p(n),q(n)$ such that the following inequality holds asymptotically:
$$p(n)\leq \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\leq q(n)$$

For the first problem, we have the ratio is equal to $\log(n)$. It is not the case that there exist polynomials $p(n),q(n)$ such that $p(n)\leq \log(n)\leq q(n)$ asymptotically, because no polynomial is a lower bound for $\log(n)$. Thus it is not polynomially bounded. $n\log(n)$ is the same (even the same quotient if taken in the other order).

For the second problem, we have the ratio is equal to $n\log(n)$. It is the case that $n\leq n\log(n)\leq n^2$ asymptotically, so it is polynomially bounded and therefore $n^2$ is polynomially larger. $\frac{n^2}{n\log(n)}=\frac{n}{\log(n)}$, and we have that (asymptotically) $$n^\frac{1}{3}\leq \frac{n}{\log(n)}\leq n$$

Comment: So basically the quotient of the larger over the smaller function needs to be greater than $n^k$ for $k>0$, is that right?

Comment: It needs to fall between two (generalized) polynomials. I added a formal statement. Notably fractional exponents are allowed (and generally count as polynomials for complexity theory)

Comment: So I suppose it is easy to just have $n^{\text{huge number}}$ for the upper bound in practice, hard part is seeing if lower bound exists. How do I know that $n / \log(n) \geq n^{1/3}$?

Comment: That can be rearranged to give $n^{2/3}\geq\log(n)$ which can be shown a number of ways. It is not too hard to show that $\log(n)\leq n^c$ for every $c>0$ (asymptotically)

Comment: If I have $n / \log(n) \geq n^k$ then $n/n^k  \geq  \log(n)$ implies $n^{1-k} \geq \log(n)$, so I suppose this means $1-k>0$ is sufficient, or $1>k$? Any $k$ less than $1$ will satisfy the lower bound?

Comment: Yup! I just picked one-third.

Comment: @StellaBiderman You said:

It is not the case that there exist polynomials $p(n), q(n)$ such that $p(n) \leq \log n \leq q(n)$. If you set $p(n) = n^0, q(n) = n$, then this inequality will be true. right?

Comment: @Drupalist Yes, that is true. However that doesn't count in this context. Notice that Aruka's first comment says "larger than $n^k$ for $k > 0$."